# Unit test a method reading file

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I search on net but couldnt find proper solution. My issue is I want to test my readFileToList method which is make a filter in the file(csv) and; create List of objects. 
Its okay in my application I try to test this with following method in unit test project:

```
        [TestMethod]
        public void readingFile()
        {
           HomeController controller = new HomeController();
           List<City> result = controller.readFileToList("sample_data.csv", Pairing.Of("cityname", "Antalya"));
           Assert.AreEqual(83, result.Count);//"cityname" equals to Antalya is 83 
        }
```

I debug this test and see the error in of the function; "HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath" return null, and I wonder how can I handle this and next coming issues for testing this method. 
I just want this test check count of generated file equals to expected count(83)

function:

```
public List<City> readFileToList(string filename, params KeyValuePair<string, object>[] queryparams)
        {
            string fullName = Path.Combine(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, "App_Data", filename);
            string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fullName);
            IQueryable<City> cities = lines.Skip(1).Select(l => new City
            {
                name = l.Split(',')[0],
                cityCode = Convert.ToInt32(l.Split(',')[1]),
                district = l.Split(',')[2],
                zipCode = l.Split(',')[3],
            }).AsQueryable();
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> item in queryparams)
            {
                if (item.Key == "cityname" && item.Value.ToString() != "0")
                    cities = cities.Where(w => w.cityCode.ToString() == item.Value.ToString());               
            }
               return cities.ToList();
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you don't worry much about [unittesting actual Input/Output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16541571/unit-testing-methods-with-file-io), I'd say that the method you are trying to test has not one, but at least [two responsibilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle):

1. Determine the server path of some file.
2. Parse that file.

You may leave it as it is if your testing framework [supports mocking of static members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34122823/shimming-a-class-instantiated-by-a-static-class) (you can just mock/fake the `HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath` to return some test file path) or [abstract the HttpRuntime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416362/mock-static-property-with-moq), but I'd recommend you to split `readFileToList` into two methods:

1. `GetCsvFileServerPath(String csvFileName)` - that will `Path.Combine(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, "App_Data", filename);`
2. `public List<City> ReadFileToList(string fullServerFilePath, params KeyValuePair<string, object>[] queryparams)` that processes a file at the `fullServerFilePath` returned by the `GetCsvFileServerPath(String csvFileName)`

So the second method can be relatively easily unittested without [additional changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416362/mock-static-property-with-moq).

**P.S.:** If you have some time and want to do more proper unittesting, you may try to [abstract file IO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087351/how-do-you-mock-out-the-file-system-in-c-sharp-for-unit-testing), or **at least separate file reading and processing**, because `ReadFileToList` both reads and processes the file, that is more difficult to test.

Comment: "if your testing framework supports mocking of static members". I dont think so. How can I add this ? is it VS native library or third party component?

Comment: @TyForHelpDude Not all testing frameworks/3rd party libs support it. The reference I gave you discusses [MS Fakes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx) (and it is not free - you have to use full VS - https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/2919309-provide-microsoft-fakes-with-all-visual-studio-edi). Some other free frameworks support such things, but not many. In any case it is better to separate file path calculation and actual parsing.